# Prove that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\geq 0$

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$ and that $f^2(x)=2\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ for all $x>0$.  Prove that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\geq 0$.

Attempt at a proof:
Let $f(t)=t$ for all $t\geq 0$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, $f(t)=t$ is integrable.
Then 
\begin{align*}
f^2(x)&=2\int_0^x f(t)\, dt \\
           &=2\int_0^x t\, dt \\
           &=2\frac{t^2}{2}\Big|_0^x \\
           &=2\frac{x^2}{2} \\
           &=x^2
\end{align*}
Therefore $f(x)=x$ for all $x\geq 0$.

Comment: In the first sentence of your attempted proof you are assuming what you intend to prove.

Comment: You've shown that $f(x) = x$ satisfies the integral equation, not that the integral equation implies $f(x) = x$.

Comment: I am not quite sure how I can get the integral equation to implies that f(x)=x then.  Should I take the derivative of both sides and solve it that way?

Comment: Yes, that will give it to you quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

derivative of both sides gives you $2f(x)*f'(x)=2f(x) $ so $f'(x)=1$ imples that $f(x)=x$

Comment: in fact implies that $f(x)=x+c$ and because $f(0)=0$, then $c=0$.

Comment: I am sorry ,I was just in my way to bed :D

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right. Take the derivative of both sides using the chain rule and FTC. Divide by f (which is not zero) and integrate.